# Bluetooth USB Adapter

Tags: 14.04, sound, bluetooth, headphones

Trying to get Bluetooth USB working on my Toshiba Satellite. Tried typing a few things in Terminal from answers to similar Questions (bash_history):

```
57  sudo apt-get clean  
58  sudo apt-get update  
59  sudo apt-get install -f  
60  sudo apt-get upgrade  
61  sudo hciconfig hci0 reset  
62  rfkill list  
63  udo rfkill unblock bluetooth  
64  sudo apt-get install udo  
65  sudo hciconfig hci0 reset  
66  sudo apt-get install gksu -y  
67  gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local  
68  sudo reboot  
69  sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth  
70  rfkill list  
71  sudo apt-get install gksu -y  
72  apt-get autoremove  
73  sudo apt-get install gksu -y  
74  /etc/rc.local  
75  edit /etc/rc.local 


tracy@tracy-Satellite-P100:~$ lsusb  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
```

- Bluetooth is not an option in the Sound Settings or in PaVu Configuration settings.
- When I try to connect my device via Bluetooth settings, it simply won't connect and will return to "Connection: off" even though it acknowledges that it's paired.

The Bluetooth icon in the top right used to get a padlock image next to it, but that doesn't happen anymore. Now, the icon just looks grey, as if it's not activated. When I click on the Bluetooth icon, however,  it says that "Bluetooth" is on and the Bluetooth device "Sennheiser MM400-X" is on, too.

Says Bluetooth is neither soft nor hard blocked.

I can't post any images yet, sorry.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please be more specific about what you have tried. If you can't remember that have a look in your bash history.

Comment: Just added it to the question.

Comment: Have you already tried to delete the device in Bluetooth Settings and pair it again? This helped me with my Sennheiser MM450-X a while ago.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: @Germar I disconnected my headphones and now it won't even find them to pair with it.

Comment: @Pilot6 can you please tell me the exact line for Terminal?

Comment: I gave you the exact line.

Comment: Okay I edited the question.

Comment: Please make sure Bluetooth is enabled on the `MM400-X` and it is in connection mode. My `MM450-X` is sometimes a bit strange on this... Also make sure it's not connected to any other device (e.g. your mobile, just deactivate Bluetooth on this for a while)

Comment: Still not connecting. It won't connect to my phone via Bluetooth, either; however, the headphones and the phone do sync up via Bluetooth.

Comment: Alright I got the Bluetooth up and running. Thanks for your help. The quality, however, is really bad. How can I fix this? I think the audio is set as mono and I can't figure out how to make it stereo.

Comment: @Tarce ask a new question about the sound settings (have a look into *system settings* / *sound*.